# mysql: NOT MATCH vs NOT IN subquery for fulltext search

Tags: mysql

I want to find all rows that match a full-text search for one pair of columns but also do *not* match the same text in another column.

Both of these seem to work

```
SELECT * FROM docs WHERE MATCH(title, descript) AGAINST ('energy' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND NOT MATCH(categories) AGAINST ('energy' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Or using a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM docs WHERE MATCH(title, descript) AGAINST ('energy' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM docs where MATCH(categories) AGAINST ('energy' IN BOOLEAN MODE));
```

The docs field has the relevant full-text indexes set up.

Any reason to prefer one over the other?

On the (small) database I'm using they are both very fast, too fast to measure reliably.

Thanks for any suggestions.